# Constructing RequestBodyStream from Lazy ByteString when length is known

Tags: haskell, bytestring, http-conduit

I am trying to adapt this [AWS S3 upload code](https://github.com/aristidb/aws/blob/master/Examples/PutObjectIA.hs) to handle `Lazy ByteString` where length is already known (so that it is not forced to be read in its entirety in memory - it comes over the network where length is sent beforehand). It seems I have to define a [`GivesPopper`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.28/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#t:GivesPopper) function over `Lazy ByteString` to convert it to [`RequestBodyStream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.4.24/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:RequestBodyStream). Because of the convoluted way `GivesPopper` is defined, I am not sure how to write it for `Lazy ByteString`. Will appreciate pointers on how to write it. [Here](https://github.com/aristidb/aws/blob/master/Examples/PutObjectIA.hs#L27) is how it is written for reading from the file:

```
let file ="test"
-- streams large file content, without buffering more than 10k in memory
let streamer sink = withFile file ReadMode $ \h -> sink $ S.hGet h 10240
```

`streamer` in the code above is of type `GivesPopper ()` if I understand it correctly.
Given a `Lazy ByteString` with known length `len`, what would be a good way to write `GivesPopper` function over it? We can read one chunk at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import qualified Data.ByteString as S
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L
import System.IO

file = "test"
-- original streamer for feeding a sink from a file
streamer :: (IO S.ByteString -> IO r) -> IO r
streamer sink = withFile file ReadMode $ \h -> sink $ S.hGet h 10240

-- feed a lazy ByteString to sink    
lstreamer :: L.ByteString -> (IO S.ByteString -> IO r) -> IO r
lstreamer lbs sink = sink (return (L.toStrict lbs))
```

`lstreamer` type checks but probably doesn't do exactly what you want it to do. It simply returns the same data every time the sink calls it. On the other hand `S.hGet h ...` will eventually return the empty string.

Here is a solution which uses an IORef to keep track of if we should start returning the empty string:

```
import Data.IORef

mklstream :: L.ByteString -> (IO S.ByteString -> IO r) -> IO r
mklstream lbs sink = do
  ref <- newIORef False
  let fetch :: IO S.ByteString
      fetch = do sent <- readIORef ref
                 writeIORef ref True
                 if sent
                   then return S.empty
                   else return (L.toStrict lbs)
  sink fetch
```

Here `fetch` is the action which gets the next chunk. The first time you call it you will get the original lazy Bytestring (strict-ified). Subsequent calls will always return the empty string.

**Update**

Here's how to give out a small amount at a time:

```
mklstream :: L.ByteString -> (IO S.ByteString -> IO r) -> IO r
mklstream lbs sink = do
  ref <- newIORef (L.toChunks lbs)
  let fetch :: IO S.ByteString
      fetch = do chunks <- readIORef ref
                 case chunks of
                   [] -> return S.empty
                   (c:cs) -> do writeIORef ref cs
                                return c
  sink fetch
```

Comment: Isn't this solution going to read the entire lazy bytestring into memory because of `L.toStrict` call? We want to read one chunk at a time, or place an upper bound on memory usage.

Comment: Well - it shows you how to create some state (an IORef) to keep track of what you've already given out. Note that unless you're using lazy-IO they lazy byte string is already in memory.

Comment: It should probably be said that the updated `mklstream` relies on the invariant that a lazy bytestring never has an empty bytestring chunk. It would be clearer that it does what `http-client` wants if the ref were defined with `newIORef (filter (not . S.null) (L.toChunks lbs))`, but it doesn't need to do this, if I understand. Then it has the desired structure, which is to be like [`hGet`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v:hGet)

Comment: The same result comes more or less prepackaged with `io-streams`. There you would write `ref <- Streams.fromLazyByteString lbs` and then the `fetch` function would be something like `fmap (maybe S.empty id) (Streams.read ref)`

Comment: @Michael, yep, good point about `io-streams`. I took a look at the implementation there. Wondering if `writeIORef` in the code above is efficient because the way it pops top of the stack is by rewriting the new stack after removing the top element. `io-streams` too has similar logic in `makeInputStream`. So, it is likely to be efficient, I guess.